# How does es6 let work with console.log in a if statement?

Tags: javascript

Why does the console.log return undefined? Even if `let` limits the scope of `v`, that scope is within the `if` statement (which is also where the `console.log` is), so shouldn't it still get logged?

```
var x = 1;

if(x < 10) {
    let v = 1;
    v = v + 21;
    v = v * 100;
    v = v / 8;

    console.log(v);
}

console.log(v); //v is not defined
```

Comment: `v` isn't defined outside the `if` statement, hence the undefined output from `console.log` outside of the if

Comment: You are saying that the log statement within the if is reporting undefined?

Comment: Variables being declared with let have a block scope. So these variables only can be accessed in that block where variable being declared. Because of it, the first 'console.log' can access v, but the second 'console.log' can not access v in the example code.

you can see more in detail: https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: @mangocaptain Which of the two log statements are you talking about?

Comment: `console.log` only receives the value. It can't know if it was a `let` variable, a `var` variable, an expression, or whatever. So it's unrelated.

Comment: I was referring to the 2nd console.log, but I get it now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Variable declared let is limited within if block.